# Latin suffixes -or and -idus, is there a correspondence?

Tags: etymology, morphology, latin, italian

In Latin (and daughter languages), there seems to be a correspondence between nouns of the third declension in -or/-us, -oris denoting a quality, and adjectives of the Ist class in -idus,a,um denoting something or someone possessing the corresponding quality (sometimes approximately, I guess out of semantic drift).

Here are the ones that I could find in Italian (some in Latin). I'm sure there are more, but these are already many enough to suggest a pattern:

- CALOR, CALIDUS (Latin)
- FRIGUS, FRIGIDUS (Latin)
- HUMOR (as in liquid), HUMIDUS (Latin)
- AMOR (as in cohesion), AMIDUS (Latin)
- timore, timido (Italian)
- pavore, pavido
- pallore, pallido
- candore, candido
- squallore, squallido
- valore, valido
- fetore, fetido
- sapore, sapido
- tumore, tumido

So, what is the pattern, and how did it originate? Is this appearing also in other IE languages?

Comment: Latin SE would be a good place for this question.

Comment: If *-or* stems from *-ios* after rhotacizm (as in *maioris*), and if *-s* is nominative (for nominalized adjectives), then you would have to compare *-r* (*-s) and *-dus*, eventually. If *-d-* can be understood the same as in *cre-do*, then calidus is approximately *warm-ing*, that which makes *warm*, whereas calor is simply warm. Yes? To be honest, I have no idea if that makes sense. Otherwise I would post it in a more complete form as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to Wiktionary, [-idus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-idus) is "suffix forming adjectives", but most of the words in the [Category:Latin words suffixed with -idus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Latin_words_suffixed_with_-idus), are based on a verb.

[-or](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-or#Latin) is similarly "used to form a third-declension masculine abstract noun from a verb root or conceived root form"

So the relationship is that these are morphemes commonly used to form an adjective and an abstract noun respectively from a (usually verbal) root.

Comment: Right. Basic derivational morphology, [with all its properties](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Inflection.pdf).